# Vapor Signed Storage URL 401 with Nova

Tags: laravel-nova, laravel-vapor

I'm trying to get file uploads to work in my Laravel Nova on a Vapor server.
When I try to upload, it keeps showing me a 401 response on /vapor/signed-storage-url.

What am I missing?

This is my Nova Resource:

```
public function fields(Request $request)
{
   return [
    VaporFile::make('Attachment')->rules('bail', 'required', function ($attribute, $value, $fail) use ($request) {
        if (Storage::size($request->input('vaporFile')[$attribute]['key']) > 1000000) {
            return $fail('The document size may not be greater than 1 MB');
        }
    }),
```

This is added to my app.js:

```
window.Vapor = require("laravel-vapor");
```

This is my registered policy:

```
class UserPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can upload files.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function uploadFiles(User $user)
    {
        return true; 
    }
```

Looks to me I've done everything correctly.. but it still fails.

Comment: Do you use any custom auth guard for Laravel Nova?